# Vectors ratio help

Tags: vectors

When it comes to vectors..

when B,G,E is collinear and $BG:BE $ is $λ:1$.....GE should be $1-λ$ right?....

and can $λ$ be negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I think you mean to ask whether it's also true that
$$
GE : BE = (1-\lambda) : 1,
$$
and that is correct (assuming that "GE" means "the distance from $G$ to $E$, etc.).

When you ask whether $\lambda$ can be negative...well, in what you've written: if you have $BG : BE = \lambda : 1$, then since both $BG$ and $BE$ are nonnegative (being distances!), their ratio cannot be negative.

What *is* true is the following: if $B, G, E$ are collinear points, and we let
$$
v = G - B
$$
be the vector from $B$ to $G$, and let 
$$
w = E - B
$$
be the vector from $B$ to $E$, and let
$$
u = E-G
$$
be the vector from $E$ to $G$, then if 
$$
v = \lambda w
$$
for some $\lambda$, we also have
$$
u = (1-\lambda) w
$$
and this is true regardless of whether we have $B-G-E$, $G-E-B$, or any other between-ness ordering of the points, and is also true whether $\lambda$ is positive or negative.

Indeed, we can go further: if $\lambda < 0$, then the points are ordered $G-B-E$; if $0 < \lambda < 1$, they're ordered $B-G-E$; if $1 < \lambda$, they're ordered $B-E-G$.

Arguably this is one of the reasons to use vectors: they let you form combinations of things with non-positive coefficients.